# Store the line break from textarea , store to database and show on frontend?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, textarea

Currently I am working on storing textarea paragraph

```
<textarea rows="10"></textarea>
```

I can save the whole content but the problem is it does not include line breaks. I wonder what is the best practice of storing the space/line break from the textarea to database. Also, I need to prevent the user from inserting the  inside the textarea.

Is it good parctice ?

```
e.g.
text=replace(text,"/n","<br>")
text=replace(text," ","&nbsp;") 
text=replace(text,"<script>","") 
text=replace(text,"</script>","")
```

Thanks

Comment: it does store line breaks, your just expecting the bowser to use them, when the browser is expecting html- short solution `nl2br()`

Comment: Thanks. That means I just need to insert the data directly to database instead of any modification?

Comment: The newline escape in PHP strings is `"\n"` and not `/n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does store linebreaks, but when you do output in HTML you can not see it.
Use `nl2br()` function to convert linebreaks into `<br />` tag so you can see linebreaks in HTML.

If you want to prevent some HTML tags in the text - use `strip_tags()` function (you can allow some tags if you wish). And don't forget to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or something like this to escape data.

Answer (score 3):

Another options except what Paul suggested are

1. Use the `<pre>` tag that actually brakes lines with /n .. that way you don't need to manipulate the text..
   you will have to custom style the `<pre>` block as the defaults resembles console fonts and styles.
2. Use a disabled  tag with custom styling to avoid manipulation of the text.

here is a fiddle to display both examples (I used JS to inject the values but it should work when you inject the from PHP as well):
http://jsfiddle.net/BvynR/

```
<pre id="pre">   
</pre>
<textarea id="textarea" disabled="disabled">
</textarea>


var str = "Hello I'm a pre-formatedt text \nand this is a new line";
$("#pre").html(str);

$("#textarea").text(str);


#pre
{
    font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
}

#textarea
{
    font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:1em;
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would be inserting the data in exactly as you received it from the user. This is because you might need to pull out that data sometime in the future, and **not** have it in HTML - eg for a report or putting into a spreadsheet or someething else.

Of course you then need to be extra careful about pulling data out and displaying it on the page - but you should be doing that anyway, and you don't want to be relying on your input sanitation being perfect - you might need to replace/update it in the future.